# How to report progress of download file but overall progress and not per file to progressBar?

Tags: c#, winforms

```
public void DownloadFile(string urlAddress, string location)
        {
            Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
            using (WebClient webClient = new WebClient())
            {
                webClient.Headers.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:67.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/67.0 Chrome");
                webClient.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler((sender, e) => Completed(sender, e, sw));
                webClient.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler((sender, e) => ProgressChanged(sender, e, sw));
                Uri URL = new Uri(urlAddress);
                sw.Start();
                try
                {
                    webClient.DownloadFileAsync(URL, location);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                }
            }
        }

        private void ProgressChanged(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e, Stopwatch sw)
        {
            string downloadProgress = e.ProgressPercentage + "%";
            string downloadSpeed = string.Format("{0} MB/s", (e.BytesReceived / 1024.0 / 1024.0 / sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds).ToString("0.00"));
            string downloadedMBs = Math.Round(e.BytesReceived / 1024.0 / 1024.0) + " MB";
            string totalMBs = Math.Round(e.TotalBytesToReceive / 1024.0 / 1024.0) + " MB";

            // Format progress string
            string progress = $"{downloadedMBs}/{totalMBs} ({downloadProgress}) @ {downloadSpeed}"; // 10 MB / 100 MB (10%) @ 1.23 MB/s

            progressBarText1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
            progressBarText1.Refresh();
            progressBarText1.CustomText = progress;
        }

        private void Completed(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e, Stopwatch sw)
        {
            if (e.Cancelled == true)
            {
                btnStartDownload.Text = "Fails.";
                sw.Stop();
            }
            else
            {
                btnStartDownload.Text = "Finish.";
                sw.Stop();

                if (videosLinks.Count > 0)
                {
                    videosLinks.RemoveAt(0);
                    string fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(videosLinks[0]);
                    DownloadFile(videosLinks[0], @"D:\Videos\videos\" + fileName);
                }
            }
        }

        static readonly string[] SizeSuffixes =
                  { "bytes", "KB", "MB", "GB", "TB", "PB", "EB", "ZB", "YB" };
        static string SizeSuffix(Int64 value, Int64 totalValue)
        {
            if (value < 0) { return "-" + SizeSuffix(-value, totalValue); }

            int i = 0;
            decimal dValue = (decimal)value;
            while (Math.Round(dValue / 1024) >= 1)
            {
                dValue /= 1024;
                i++;
            }

            return string.Format("{0:n1} {1} {2}", dValue, SizeSuffixes[i], (totalValue / 1024d / 1024d).ToString("0.00"));
        }
```

this is working fine but it's reporting the progress download per file.

how can i make that it will also report progress of the overall downloads ?
i added another progressbar name progressBar2 and to this i want to report the overall download process and not per file like i do to progressBar1.

Comment: What's the problem? The math? Just sum the last reported progress percentages of all downloads and divide it by the number of all downloads to get the total progress percentage across all downloads.

Comment: @MySkullCaveIsADarkPlace i need to do it in the ProgressChanged event or in the Completed event ? not sure how to do it.

Comment: Start with thinking about your "business" logic, don't start with thinking about implementation details first. Start with thinking about _WHEN_ has the total progress percentage (TPP) to change. The TPP has to be changed _whenever_ the progress percentage of a download changes, right? So, now, back to your question, and allow me to throw back the ball to you: Approaching it like that, where do you think is the place or what is the event where you - or rather your code - knows that the progress percentage of a download just changed? ;-)

Comment: Now, there is of course the (final) value of 100% of a download progress to consider here, which i am not sure whether the ProgressChanged event will report or not (you'll need to figure this out). If it does not, you have to view the DownloadFileCompleted event as the event reporting 100% progress for a download.

Answer (score 0):

This is a working solution.

```
using System;
using System.Buffers;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web;
using System.Windows.Forms;
 
namespace Download_Videos
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private List<string> videosLinks = new List<string>();
        private int filesCounter = 0;
        long sizes = 0;
        long _received = 0;
 
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
 
            progressBarText1.DisplayStyle = ProgressBarDisplayText.CustomText;
            lblFilesCount.Text = "";
 
            string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Users\tester\OneDrive\randfiles\");
            foreach(string file in files)
            {
                videosLinks.Add(file);
            }
            lblFilesCount.Text = videosLinks.Count.ToString();
            filesCounter = videosLinks.Count;
 
            foreach(string file in files)
            {
                long size = new System.IO.FileInfo(file).Length;
                sizes = sizes + size;
            }
        }
 
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
 
        }
 
        private void DownloadSources(string sourceLink, string destFile)
        {
            using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
            {
                client.Headers.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:67.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/67.0 Chrome");
                client.DownloadFile(sourceLink, destFile);
            }
        }
 
        private void btnStartDownload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (videosLinks.Count > 0)
            {
                string fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(videosLinks[0]);
                DownloadFile(videosLinks[0], @"D:\Videos\videos\" + fileName);
            }
        }
 
        public void DownloadFile(string urlAddress, string location)
        {
            Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
            using (WebClient webClient = new WebClient())
            {
                webClient.Headers.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:67.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/67.0 Chrome");
                webClient.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler((sender, e) => Completed(sender, e, sw));
                webClient.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler((sender, e) => ProgressChanged(sender, e, sw));
 
                Uri URL = new Uri(urlAddress);
                sw.Start();
                try
                {
                    webClient.DownloadFileAsync(URL, location);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                }
            }
        }
 
        private void ProgressChanged(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e, Stopwatch sw)
        {
            string downloadProgress = e.ProgressPercentage + "%";
            string downloadSpeed = string.Format("{0} MB/s", (e.BytesReceived / 1024.0 / 1024.0 / sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds).ToString("0.00"));
            string downloadedMBs = Math.Round(e.BytesReceived / 1024.0 / 1024.0) + " MB";
            string totalMBs = Math.Round(e.TotalBytesToReceive / 1024.0 / 1024.0) + " MB";
 
            // Format progress string
            string progress = $"{downloadedMBs}/{totalMBs} ({downloadProgress}) @ {downloadSpeed}"; // 10 MB / 100 MB (10%) @ 1.23 MB/s
 
            progressBarText1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
            progressBarText1.Refresh();
            progressBarText1.CustomText = progress;
 
            var result = (double)(_received + e.BytesReceived) / sizes * 100;
            progressBarText2.Value = (int)result;
            progressBarText2.Refresh();
        }
 
        private void Completed(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e, Stopwatch sw)
        {
            if (e.Cancelled == true)
            {
                btnStartDownload.Text = "Fails.";
                sw.Stop();
            }
            else
            {
                btnStartDownload.Text = "Finish.";
                sw.Stop();
 
                filesCounter--;
                lblFilesCount.Text = filesCounter.ToString();
                var size = new FileInfo(videosLinks[0]);
                _received += size.Length;
                videosLinks.RemoveAt(0);
                if (videosLinks.Count > 0)
                {
                    string fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(videosLinks[0]);
                    DownloadFile(videosLinks[0], @"D:\Videos\videos\" + fileName);
 
 
                }
                else
                {
                    progressBarText1.CustomText = "";
                }
            }
        }
 
        static readonly string[] SizeSuffixes =
                  { "bytes", "KB", "MB", "GB", "TB", "PB", "EB", "ZB", "YB" };
        static string SizeSuffix(Int64 value, Int64 totalValue)
        {
            if (value < 0) { return "-" + SizeSuffix(-value, totalValue); }
 
            int i = 0;
            decimal dValue = (decimal)value;
            while (Math.Round(dValue / 1024) >= 1)
            {
                dValue /= 1024;
                i++;
            }
 
            return string.Format("{0:n1} {1} {2}", dValue, SizeSuffixes[i], (totalValue / 1024d / 1024d).ToString("0.00"));
        }
    }
}
```

The progressBarText type is a custom progressbar :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Download_Videos
{
    public enum ProgressBarDisplayText
    {
        Percentage,
        CustomText
    }

    public partial class ProgressBarText : ProgressBar
    {
        //Property to set to decide whether to print a % or Text
        public ProgressBarDisplayText DisplayStyle { get; set; }
        
        //Property to hold the custom text
        public String CustomText { get; set; }

        public ProgressBarText()
        {
            // Modify the ControlStyles flags
            //http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.controlstyles.aspx
            SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint | ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint | ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer, true);
        }

        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            Rectangle rect = ClientRectangle;
            Graphics g = e.Graphics;

            ProgressBarRenderer.DrawHorizontalBar(g, rect);
            rect.Inflate(-3, -3);
            if (Value > 0)
            {
                // As we doing this ourselves we need to draw the chunks on the progress bar
                Rectangle clip = new Rectangle(rect.X, rect.Y, (int)Math.Round(((float)Value / Maximum) * rect.Width), rect.Height);
                ProgressBarRenderer.DrawHorizontalChunks(g, clip);
            }

            // Set the Display text (Either a % amount or our custom text
            int percent = (int)(((double)this.Value / (double)this.Maximum) * 100);
            string text = DisplayStyle == ProgressBarDisplayText.Percentage ? percent.ToString() + '%' : CustomText;

            using (Font f = new Font(FontFamily.GenericSerif, 14))
            {

                SizeF len = g.MeasureString(text, f);
                // Calculate the location of the text (the middle of progress bar)
                // Point location = new Point(Convert.ToInt32((rect.Width / 2) - (len.Width / 2)), Convert.ToInt32((rect.Height / 2) - (len.Height / 2)));
                Point location = new Point(Convert.ToInt32((Width / 2) - len.Width / 2), Convert.ToInt32((Height / 2) - len.Height / 2));
                // The commented-out code will centre the text into the highlighted area only. This will centre the text regardless of the highlighted area.
                // Draw the custom text
                g.DrawString(text, f, Brushes.Blue, location);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What type is `progressBarText1`?

Comment: And `ProgressBarDisplayText`?

Comment: @Enigmativity a custom progressbar pudated my answer with it.

Comment: Wait... for caluclating the total progress, you are using the field `sizes`. The value of this field is calculated from files that you already have locally on your computer. Does that mean that you attempt downloading files that you already have locally? What would be the point of doing that? And if you don't have the files you want to download already on your computer, what's the point of getting the sizes of some local files that are not the files you want to download? It's not making any sense to me. But then again, if you think that's what you want, i won't bitch any further... ;-)

Comment: My apoplogies for some more bitching and breaking of my promise to not do it. Your calculation of the total progress is flawed. You are not summing accross the progress of all downloads. You are just summing all **completed** download and then only account for whatever chunk of bytes has been downloaded last. (1/2)

Comment: (2/2) An example: To keep things simple lets assume there is only one download. The download calls ProgessChanged with reporting that it has just downloaded 20K of the file (total download so far 20K), so your code does  (`(_received + 20K) / sizes * 100`). Then the download calls ProgessChanged again, reporting now that it has downloaded a further 7K (total download so far 27K), but your code does `(_received + 7K) / sizes * 100`)` thus **decreasing** the total progress than it was before. It should have calculated `(_received + 27K) / sizes * 100`)` instead, but that's not what it does.

Comment: (P.S.: Just for sake of transparency: I downvoted your answer. Not to disparage you, but because the offered answer - the code - contains an attempted calculation of total download progress that is completely broken. Adding to that, it is presented explicitly as a "_working solution_". Which it is not. If you accept the flaws in your code and accept that it actually does not properly calculate total download progress, that's totally fine. But that does not mean that it is a working or properly functioning solution.)

Comment: @MySkullCaveIsADarkPlace my mistake , the files i'm getting from the hard disk are from the ondrive folder i thought because i copied the files to the onedrive folder that i'm downloading the files from the onedrive.  the main goal with the variable files was to simulate downloads.  i want to make something that will simulate downloads.  i forgot that i should download the files from the onedrive site server and not from the folder.  i messed it.  i will try to fix it first and then the file sizes calculation.

Comment: You don't need to sum file sizes or track how many bytes in total across all files at all here. Sure, you could do it that way, but why? Remember what i suggested in my 1st comment underneath your question? Sum the progress percentage values of the downloads. You already calculate those progress percentage values for each download, so why are you set on introducing and wanting to calculate even more data/numbers that you technically don't need instead of using what you already have to get what you want (getting the total progress percentage).

Comment: @MySkullCaveIsADarkPlace this is what i had to do ? sumPercentages = sumPercentages + e.ProgressPercentage / videosLinks.Count;
            if (sumPercentages <= 100)
            {
                progressBarText2.Value = sumPercentages;
                progressBarText2.Refresh();
            } the problem is that in the end sumPercentages value is 101 so i'm checking if it's <= 100 but not sure if this is right.  why it's 101 in the end ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247718/discussion-between-myskullcaveisadarkplace-and-dubi-duboni).